# How do you align an image to pixels in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixel, snapping

I have align to pixels turned on for new objects, but an image I placed earlier is not aligned to pixels, though it's exactly 1440 x 900. How do I set Illustrator so that when I move this image object, it will always snap to a round number?

Answer (score 1):

In the `Transform` window, make sure `Align to Pixel Grid` is checked. This will force things to snap.

[image]

**EDIT** Make sure you have a shape selected for the checkbox to work.

If that still doesn't work, go to the `Transform` menu and check `Align New Objects to Pixel Grid` and replace your image.

Also as [AdamSchuld mentioned](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21184/how-do-you-align-an-image-to-pixels-in-illustrator/21185?noredirect=1#comment29271_21185), you can set this setting when creating a new document under the `Advanced` section:

[image]

Comment: That box is greyed out and can't be checked.

Comment: Make sure you have an object selected. Or alternatively, make a new document with Align to Pixel Grid option turned on by default.

Comment: The placed image was selected, and the box is greyed out. If I select other drawn objects on the page, the option on the transform dialogue becomes available. I set the panel option for all new objects to be pixel aligned, re-placed the object, and now it's lined up right.

Comment: To be clear, "Align to Pixel Grid" does not seem to be available for placed bitmaps. That is the main point of this question...

Comment: Alright, but using the option and the replacing the object worked? i was thinking about including that in my answer but didn't think it was necessary but it seems it is. I've edited my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the screen you will see X and Y values for your object. You can manually type in the position at any time to get exact positioning.

Besides that you can shift+arrow keys to move objects in multiples of 10.

Comment: I know I can type it of course. I want to know what setting has to be checked so everything, placed or drawn, will align to the pixel grid by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have pixel preview on for it to work. To enable that, just go to View \ Pixel Preview on the top menu. That is what actually enables the snap to pixel mode in illustrator, which cannot be done any other way.

Checking *align to pixel grid* is not a good option, unless we are talking about elements made of square angle (90 degrees) lines, like rectangles and (you guessed it) 90 degree lines. When *align to pixel grid* is checked, every node in your object will try to align to the nearest pixel, which is not really a good idea, because you are going to have node quantization (it will look like bad pixel interpolation).